# How to get message body without downloading attachment

Tags: c#, .net, imap, mailkit

I am using IMAP4 client called: MailKit.
It works great, but I have a problem on getting body of message without downloading the attachments. I want to show the mail's body text and also what attachments there are,
but only if a user clicks on the attachment I want to actually download the attachment.

I've tried:

```
var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid, cancel.Token);
```

But this gets the entire message.

Also tried:

```
uids[0] = uid;
var ms = inbox.Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure , cancel.Token);  
var bp1 = inbox.GetBodyPart(uid, ms.First().Body, cancel.Token);
```

But again this downloads the attachment.

Comment: That looks plausible. What are the actual IMAP commands issued?

Comment: It sounds like you should ask support for your particular library (MailKit) in their own forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your sample code, you are downloading the entire message because you are requesting the top-level body part of the message.

MIME is a tree structure of "body parts". What you want to do is to traverse the ms.First().Body to find the part(s) that you want, and then download them individually using the GetBodyPart() method.

Take a look at MailKit.BodyPartMultipart, MailKit.BodyPartMessage, MailKit.BodyPartBasic and MailKit.BodyPartText.

A BodyPartMultipart contains other body parts.

A BodyPartMessage parts contains a message (which will also contain a body part).

A BodyPartBasic is a basic leaf-node body part - usually an "attachment".

A BodyPartText is a text part (a subclass of BodyPartBasic) which can either be an attached text part or what you might consider to be the main text of the message.

To figure out if a BodyPartBasic is meant to be displayed inline or as an attachment, what you need to do is:

```
if (part.ContentDisposition != null && part.ContentDisposition.IsAttachment)
    // it is an attachment
else
    // it is meant to be shown to the user as part of the message
    // (if it is an image, it is meant to be displayed with the text)
```

I should probably add a convenience property to BodyPartBasic called `IsAttachment` to make this a bit simpler (I'll try to add it today).

Hope that helps.

**Update:** I've just added the BodyPartBasic.IsAttachment convenience property in git master, so the next release of MailKit will have it.

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, I also added the ability to specify if you want headersOnly in git master

Comment: It take a long time (about 4sec) to do a `..Inbox.Fetch(uids,MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);` from an Exch. Online inbox with only 5 mails. Each mail do have an attachment of about 25MB. Why is that? I expect it only get meta-data, right? If I just retrieve e.g. `MessageSummaryItems.Fast` it's very fast.

Comment: I need to delete certain attachments from a mailbox with 
>100.000 mails so I need to find a quick way to find those attachments, using `MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure` would take a very long time just for finding the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

This IMAP command will return just the text body.

```
     a1 uid fetch <uid> (body.peek[text])
```

-Rick